# PDFBox: Adding a link to an attached File

Tags: java, pdf, annotations, pdfbox

I'm looking for a possibility to change an external link to a reference to an attached file. I found a sample to change the external link to an other external link, but I need to have a link to the attached file.

This is snippet of that what I found:

```
PDDocument doc = null;
    try {
        doc = PDDocument.load(pathToFile);
        List allPages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        for (int i = 0; i < allPages.size(); i++) {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) allPages.get(i);
            List annotations = page.getAnnotations();

            for (int j = 0; j < annotations.size(); j++) {
                PDAnnotation annot = (PDAnnotation) annotations.get(j);
                if (annot instanceof PDAnnotationLink) {
                    PDAnnotationLink link = (PDAnnotationLink) annot;
                    PDAction action = link.getAction();
                    if (action instanceof PDActionURI) {
                        PDActionURI uri = (PDActionURI) action;
                        String oldURI = uri.getURI();
                        System.out.println(oldURI);
                        addToAttachment(oldURI, doc);
                        String newURI = "computer1.wmf";

                        System.out.println("Page " + (i + 1)
                                + ": Replacing " + oldURI + " with "
                                + newURI);
                        uri.setURI(newURI);
```

Thanks and 
best regards

Markus

Comment: ISO-32000-1 explains how to create a link to a PDF that is added in attachment. There is no PDF syntax that allows you to link to a file of any other type that was attached to the PDF. You can create an external link to any type of file; you can only make internal links to PDF files. Are you sure you aren't asking for something that is impossible?

Comment: Hi, I'm asking about links like they are done in the kubrick_box sample in itext examples. I also tried to use itext but I didn't get it managed to extract the external links well. So I was not able to annotate the to file and replace the link with a link INSIDE the PDF.

Comment: OK, so based on the Kubrick example I once wrote, you know that what you're trying is feasible. Now it's a matter of getting it done. What do you mean by "I didn't manage to extract the external links well"? Take a look at your file using http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextrups Do you find the links you're looking for (you should). If so, you can get those links using iText (because RUPS is based on iText) and you should be able to change them using iText too.

Comment: Hi, I did what you have told me. By now I've got to a point I didn't know why it doesn't work, because the structure in kubrick box is excepting the "annots/array"-part the same. But the links doen't work.